# ASM library: Version incompatibility between GAE and Spring

Tags: eclipse, spring, google-app-engine

I'm currently working on a project based on Spring 3.1.2 which needs to run over GAE.

After researching the logs, I think I know why I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error whenever I need to interact with the App. The problem I'm facing is related with ASM (http://asm.ow2.org/).

It seems like GAE relies on ASM 4.0, while the project runs fine locally if I use ASM 3.1.

However, I found impossible to make it work when ASM 4.0 :(

I'm completely new to Google App Engine, so ... any tip to solve this issue is welcome! (I've already lost the whole morning finding what the problem was and trying too many different ways to solve it ... but no way).

Thank you very much in advance for your suggestions ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found some information about that, try to upgrade your spring version to 3.2 M2. This version support cgilib 3.0 with asm 4.0!

Visit https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9669